# Buffering issue with Exoplayer

Tags: android, buffer, exoplayer

I'm trying to set a streaming app using exoplayer, but there's something I don't get about buffering.

It is supposed to try to ensure that the buffer size is always between DEFAULT_MIN_BUFFER_MS and DEFAULT_MAX_BUFFER_MS. I can also set a DEFAULT_BUFFER_FOR_PLAYBACK_MS, which sets the buffer size required for starting to play the stream.

But whenever I set the DEFAULT_BUFFER_FOR_PLAYBACK_MS lower than the DEFAULT_MIN_BUFFER_MS, it seems that DEFAULT_MIN_BUFFER_MS takes the value of the DEFAULT_BUFFER_FOR_PLAYBACK_MS.

For example : if I set DEFAULT_MIN_BUFFER_MS to 10000, DEFAULT_MAX_BUFFER_MS to 20000 & DEFAULT_BUFFER_FOR_PLAYBACK_MS to 5000, then my buffer size will stay between 5 seconds and 20 seconds instead of 10 to 20. Is this expected or am I missing something in the way I set my player ?

Here's a sample of my code, feel free to ask if you need more :

```
public static final int DEFAULT_MIN_BUFFER_MS = 10000;
public static final int DEFAULT_MAX_BUFFER_MS = 20000;
public static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_FOR_PLAYBACK_MS = 5000;
public static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_FOR_PLAYBACK_AFTER_REBUFFER_MS = 5000;

DefaultLoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl.Builder()
               .setAllocator(new DefaultAllocator(true, C.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE))
                .setBufferDurationsMs(DEFAULT_MIN_BUFFER_MS,
                        DEFAULT_MAX_BUFFER_MS, DEFAULT_BUFFER_FOR_PLAYBACK_MS, DEFAULT_BUFFER_FOR_PLAYBACK_AFTER_REBUFFER_MS)
                .setPrioritizeTimeOverSizeThresholds(true)
                .createDefaultLoadControl();

player = newSimpleInstance(this,defaultRenderersFactory, trackSelector, loadControl, null, bandwidthMeter);
```